# HighCharts in R Shiny App

Tags: highcharts, shiny

I am using highcharts in a shiny app. When I have the following, everything works.

```
fluidRow(  tags$head(tags$script(src = "https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"),
                   tags$script(src = "https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"),
                   tags$script(src = "https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"),
                   tags$script(src = "https://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"),
                   tags$style(type="text/css",
                              ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
                              ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }")
```

However my goal is to not go through the highcharts website and access the highcharts folder locally. I placed the highcharts folder in the root directory and did the following.

```
fluidRow(  tags$head(tags$script(src = "/HighCharts/js/highcharts.js"),
                   tags$script(src = "/HighCharts/js/highcharts-more.js"),
                   tags$script(src = "/HighCharts/js/modules/exporting.js"),
                   tags$script(src = "/HighCharts/js/modules/heatmap.js"),
                   tags$style(type="text/css",
                              ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
                              ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }")
```

I am getting nothing but errors. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you use `rCharts`? Using this library you can easily make Highcharts charts etc.

Comment: Also you can use Highstock hack with `rCharts`, which can be found here https://github.com/nemonominem/Highstock-rCharts-hack

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your files in a `www` folder in the root of your shiny app.

so based on your path of `/HighCharts/js/modules/` you would have a folder structure of:

```
root/
  +-www/
    +-HighCharts/
      +-js/
        - hightcharts.js
        - highcharts-more.js
        +-modules/
          - exporting.js
          - heatmap.js
```